# Pygame Sprite not updating

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move a paddle in a game of Pong by using the up and down arrows. I am doing this through an event handling loop. Here is the code for the event handling loop:

```
    for event in PE.get():
       if event.type == PG.KEYDOWN:
          keystate = PG.key.get_pressed()
          if event.key == PG.K_ESCAPE:
              done = True
          if keystate[PL.K_UP]:
              rightPaddle.update(-10)
          if keystate[PL.K_DOWN]:
              rightPaddle.update(10)
       if event.type == PG.QUIT:
          done = True
```

The update function is shown below:

```
   def update(self, move):
       self.toplefty += move
```

And here is the PaddleSprite Class:

```
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        PG.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = PG.Surface([15,100])
        self.topleftx = x
        self.toplefty = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect
        self.rect.move_ip(self.topleftx, self.toplefty)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.fill(PINK, self.rect)

    def update(self, move):
        self.toplefty += move
```

Simply put, the update function for the paddle (which is essentially a rectangle) moves the top left corner of the rectangle to a new y position based on how many times the up or down arrow is clicked. Each up or down arrow increments the paddle a distance of 10 in either the positive or negative direction. However, in my program, the paddle is not moving at all when I press up or down. Can anyone tell me why? Furthermore, is it possible to move the paddles while I hold down the up or down key rather than me pressing it multiple times to move it?

Comment: Could you post the source for the full program?

Comment: What kind of debugging have you tried so far? Any print statements in the event handler in order to verify that the coordinate adjustment logic is being reached?

Comment: I added print statements to the event driven loop to see if it would recognize the key up and key down events. It does print out when I press the key, but the paddle does not move, which is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have combined 2 ways of checking for input. They seem to be conflicting.
Let us take a look:

```
for event in PE.get():
```

this is called a event loop, what pygame does, is stores an input queue of all the events that have happened, and a get(), pops the value from the queue.

The other method is `PG.key.get_pressed()`.

This is a more of a hardware approach, since it returns an array of button states.

To fix this, I recommend removing the `get_pressed()` call along with the keystate[] checks and replace them with `event.key == PG.K_UP`.

EDIT:

It seems that your error is setting a variable of self.toplefty, but using a self.rect to draw. You should use self.rect.move_ip to update, so that it moves the actual rect.

Comment: I made the changes but the paddle still doesn't move. I put print statements in the event handling loop to see if it recognizes whether I'm pressing the up or down key, which it does. This would mean that it could possibly be something with my update() method, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work:

```
   def update(self, move):
       self.rect.centerx += 0
       self.rect.centery += move
```

Essentially, the problem had to be with update because the event driven loop recognized I was pressing up or down. So I just got the Rect object of the sprite and moved its center in the vertical axis. Thanks to everyone who commented or answered!